# Why is Firefox closing null html tags?

Tags: html, firefox, tags

I have noticed in Firefox that when I view source it is adding closing tags to null tag items such as `<hr>` and `<img src="image.jpg">`. Viewing source in Firefox I see `<hr></hr>` and `<img src="image.jpg"></img>`. The document is HTML 5 and not XHTML, and the tags are null tags which should not strictly be closed in HTML. So why is Firefox doing this?

Comment: Firefox doesn't modify your HTML.  Your HTML is parsed and turned into the DOM.  Your developer tools show you an HTML representation of that DOM, which is not the same thing as what you see when you actually view the source, which should be the real output from your server.  If you're seeing this stuff when viewing source, that would be the code sent from your server.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you are not just using view source, but are instead using the Firefox Developer Tools Browser Inspector?  This is done because there has to be an end to each tag so the inspector is explicitly showing this end point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I meant that it was showing up in "Inspect element", not "view source" (it was the end of a long day). However, you haven't really answered the question just by saying there has to be an end to each tag. That surely only applies to XHTML. As I understand it, it is actually incorrect syntax to close a null tag in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

The code inspection frames of both Chrome 55.0 and Firefox 50.0.2 show the img and link tags in THIS page with neither self closing slashes nor trailing closing tags for me. (Details: I am running 64 bit Fedora 24 but would expect the same behavior on other platforms.)

Perhaps you have an old version of Firefox, but it is more likely that the page you were inspecting did not have the correct !DOCTYPE tag at its start to inform Firefox to interpret as HTML5, which, as you indicated, specifies to NOT close br, hr, img, input, meta, link, and several other tags that MUST be leaves in the document tree.