# Why does Firefox display empty elements with closing tags in its web inspector?

Tags: xml, html, firefox

As HTML5 is not an XML-based language, we can forget the self closing tags. That's great. So when I want to insert a new horizontal line, I just write `<hr>` and not `<hr />`.

But when I inspect the `<hr>` element in Firefox, it renders as `<hr></hr>`. It does not happen in any other browser.

Why does this happen? Is this some compatibility issue with Firefox?

Comment: That seems to be a Firefox quirk. It doesn't happen in any other browser. If this question were "Why does Firefox display void elements with end tags in its web inspector?" it would be a very interesting one.

Comment: Do you recommend me to rename the question?

Comment: If you don't mind, I can edit it for you.

Comment: I have wondered this myself.

Comment: Note that this happens whether you write `<hr>` or `<hr/>`.

Comment: That is true indeed. As well as just about any element, really - it doesn't have to be a void element, or even an element where the `/>` syntax makes sense, because it's essentially meaningless in HTML5.

Comment: Voting to re-open because the details of a technical implementation are not opinionated whatsoever.

Comment: It happens that way because that's how the rendering engine that Firefox uses does things (off topic as to why it does it as that would have to be asked of the people that wrote it). Compatibility with what though?  Does it cause any know issues?  I don't think this should be re-opened as the question isn't clear in that regard.

Comment: @TylerH Thank you, I did not understood, why was this closed, with 6 upvotes.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Well a questions popularity does not determine its on-topicness. However, the close reason, "primarily opinion-based" is **definitely** not correct.

Comment: But it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892583/why-is-firefox-closing-null-html-tags?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

That is just a quirky behaviour of the Firefox browser.

EDIT: Sorry, but I could not comment directly due to my SO reputation.

Comment: I won't downvote you, but I suggest you to delete this answer, because others will do. This is a comment, not a solution. And yes, maybe my question was to broad.

Answer (score 1):

Self closing tags can be dangerous because there is some browser specific behavior to them, so it is always better to write the longer form. It seems that Firefox is actually trying to help by expanding it so you will not experience some issues.

For example you can experience problems with JS frameworks using them as in this case:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1953